# Animate UIButton title with POP

Tags: objective-c, animation, uibutton, facebook-pop

I want to use POP to animate the UIButton title from right justification to left justification but I can't quite understand how to do it using their example

```
prop = [POPAnimatableProperty propertyWithName:@"com.foo.radio.volume" initializer:^(POPMutableAnimatableProperty *prop) {
  // read value
  prop.readBlock = ^(id obj, CGFloat values[]) {
    values[0] = [obj volume];
  };
  // write value
  prop.writeBlock = ^(id obj, const CGFloat values[]) {
    [obj setVolume:values[0]];
  };
  // dynamics threshold
  prop.threshold = 0.01;
}];

anim.property = prop;
```

I want to go from

```
self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

to

```
self.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know POP. But I would be very surprised if this property would be animatable.

You could add a label with the text and a transparent background on top of you button, remove the title of the button, animate the label from right to left, change the `contentHorizontalAlignment` from `...Right` to `...Left` and set the title of the button back.

Comment: thanks. that is what I did in my original implementation but I was hoping to be able to do it more simply with Pop and not have to maintain button position and label position separately and just just use the button.title property.